# Are there any circumstances where an empty String would be sent to System.out without calling the print function?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am currently doing unit tests on the code I wrote, and I noticed something weird happening. My jUnit tests are monitoring System.out and comparing correct values with my code. The thing is, even after searching though my entire project looking for all instances of (and commenting out) System.out.println, the debugger is noting that at some point, the String "" is being sent out. Are there any reasons why the ByteOutput would do this? I thought even creating a string with nothing in it would error out.

Comment: *I thought even creating a string with nothing in it would error out.* It would not. A `String` of length `0` is legal.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch nuts. Well, I'm still scratching my head trying to figure out where this gosh darn empy strinng is coming from!

Comment: There's even a method on `String` to test if the string is that string: `String.isEmpty()`.

Comment: How are you testing this?  PowerMock?

Comment: I figured it out!

Comment: If you figured it out, then feel free to answer your own question with your solution.

Comment: Will do! Sorry, still figuring out how this forum works. @JoeC

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! The test cases that were handed to me calls the Split function on System.out with the regex as \n. So, whenever I used println instead of print + \n, the string split function adds an empty string to the newly formed array.

Thanks everyone!